# Can't Get radio button value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys this is my Html Code :

```
 <div class="form_present_content">
        <span class="form_present_update">
            <fieldset class="form_present_fieldset" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <ul>
                    <li><input class="var_Amateur" name="TypeProfile[]" value="Amateur" id="Amateur" type="radio"><label for="Amateur">Amateur</label></li>
                    <li><input class="var_Professional" name="TypeProfile[]" value="Professional" id="Professional" type="radio"><label for="Professional">Professional</label></li>
                    <li><input class="var_Client" name="TypeProfile[]" value="Client" id="Client" type="radio"><label for="Client">Client</label></li>
                </ul>
            </fieldset>
        </span>
 </div>
```

I want to get the value of the radio button selected so this how i do it:

```
var var_TypeProfile = $('input[name="TypeProfile[]"]:checked', "#form_present_content").val();
alert(var_TypeProfile);
```

The alert show me Undefined , need your help and thank's.

**Edit jQuery Code:**

```
var var_TypeProfile = $('input[name="TypeProfile[]"]:checked', ".form_present_content").val();
alert(var_TypeProfile);
```

After this Edit the alert don't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
, "#form_present_content")  --> id
```

should be

```
, ".form_present_content")  --> class
```

Also when the page loads, none of the radio buttons are checked. So it is always undefined.

You need to instead write up a `change` event to get the value when checked.

```
$('input[name="TypeProfile[]"]', '.form_present_content').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9ymuyuw/)**

Comment: Look the edit i changed it but now the alert message don't show any thing

Comment: I tried your code the same thing the alert message don't appear , and code after this  isn't executed

Comment: Did you check out the fiddle that I pasted above?

Comment: Have you any suggestion why this code doesn't work and  block what is after ? i put it in the `jQuery(window).load(function () {}`

Comment: Just put it inside the `DOM` ready handler. `$(function() { });`